# Zero Values in Last Row after DGEMM

Tags: c, matrix, blas

No matter what I do here, I can't seem to get the correct results from DGEMM.  I am playing with CBLAS.

Here is the relevant code.

The main function:

```
int main ()
{
    struct Matrix* foo = new(Matrix, 3, 2, (double[6]){ 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 });
    struct Matrix* bar = new(Matrix, 2, 3, (double[6]){ 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 });
    struct Matrix* baz = matrix_mul(foo, bar);
    ...
```

Here is matrix_mul:

```
void* matrix_mul(struct Matrix* self, struct Matrix* b)
{
    struct Matrix* c;

    size_t m = self->m;
    size_t n = b->n;

    printf("%u,%u\n", m, n);

    c = new(Matrix, m, n, NULL);

    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m, n,
                self->m, 1.0, self->data, self->m, b->data, b->m, 0.0,
                c->data, m);

    return c;
}
```

When I print out the result I get this:

```
32.0 32.0 32.0
32.0 32.0 32.0
0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Although I expect:

```
32.0 32.0 32.0
32.0 32.0 32.0
32.0 32.0 32.0
```

What am I doing wrong with dgemm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CblasRowMajor`, you need to feed the second dimensions of the matrices to `lda`, `ldb`, and `ldc`. So in your case the correct call would be

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, m, n,
            self->n, 1.0, self->data, self->n, b->data, b->n, 0.0,
            c->data, n);
```

Notice that I also change the 6th parameter, which is supposed to be the "common" dimension of the two matrices.

Comment: You are correct, when I posted the question I did have that wrong.  Will update my question.